# StackApps for Windows Phone 8

Tags: discussion, api, app-request, windows-phone

Can anyone suggest a good app for Windows Phone 8 or let me know Where an I find API to build my own?

Answer (score 1):

I just finished announcing MetroStack for Windows Phone 8.1. Have a look at it.

[Metro Stack - A Windows Phone Stack Exchange app](https://stackapps.com/questions/6094/metro-stack-a-windows-phone-stack-exchange-app)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1.

- [StackCook For Windows Phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=9c34fd1b-a44f-4b5b-8932-c7c63db66bcb)
- [StackCook for Windows](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/app/stackcook/6fde7977-b260-4ca6-9369-cbca7f9e540a)

Please find more information [here](https://stackapps.com/q/6098/30879)