# Metro Stack - A Windows Phone Stack Exchange app

Tags: app, windows-phone

**Screenshot**

[image]

I’m pleased to announce **MetroStack**: A Windows Phone 8.1 app to interact with any website part of the Stack Exchange Network.

- **Sort, search** and view questions, answers, tags and users.
- **Upvote** or **downvote** questions and answers.
- Add and remove **shortcuts to websites**.
- View Stack Exchange **inbox emails**.
- Pin shortcuts to websites on your home screen.

Features currently under development include, but are not limited to are:

- Detailed profiles pages.
- Sharing via social media, messengers, etc.

Download from the Windows Phone store at: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/metrostack/4ee179b7-0c2d-4631-9d3c-3222c260f647

Comment: Yes. But can delete your comment? I'm afraid the spam bots will pick it up.

Comment: Hope it defaults to [http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/8689/106) :)

Comment: what is the different between this app and the Stack Mate app?

Comment: MetroStack allows you to do other things in the app (viewing, searching and voting on questions, answers, etc). You can also view websites that are not part of your profile. Stack Mate has functionality around your profile. Stack Mate has some features I am in the process of implementing such as notifications, profile/reputation view etc.

Comment: @LukkhaCoder: oh, so you are the author of Stack Mate too?

Comment: No. I am not the author of Stack Mate.

Comment: I am the author of Stack Mate! I probably would've added a lot more to it if more people were using it. It fulfils my need of being notified when something happens, but there have only been 700 downloads in the 1.5 years it's been around. This app looks really nice but it won't let me download it in my region (United Kingdom) so I can't see what it's like :(

Comment: Thanks for dropping by. I'm surprised that you aren't able to get to the app especially since I've published it to all available markets. Can you try this link? http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/metrostack/4ee179b7-0c2d-4631-9d3c-3222c260f647

Comment: @LukkhaCoder I just searched on my phone instead and it was fine, I don't know what I did earlier... Some things I noticed: 1. I use the light theme and all the text in the app is black on a dark blue background so it's not so easy to read, especially the questions when the text gets smaller. 2. The application bar is always shown but empty on the questions page. 3. In general it could be a bit more "Windows Phone" like. There are a lot of pages to navigate through which are just single screens. There's potential here, good job!

Comment: Thanks for the excellent feedback @Spencerooni. I'm hoping that people use pinning and secondary tiles to reduce the number of taps required to get to the place they want. I submitted a new release that has support for pinning in more places in the app. 
I made the decision of moving away from being light theme friendly in order to reduce the amount of testing work, but I plan to eventually add it back.

Comment: @LukkhaCoder I downloaded this app today and tried to log in with StackExchange account but the login form didn't load at all so I wasn't able to use the app. Any idea what's wrong? http://i.imgur.com/y0ioDcb.jpg

Comment: @Flint: This seems to be a case where StackExchange needs your account information. Can you try to recover your account? This question might shed some light: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95358/i-lost-control-of-my-account-before-registering-can-it-be-recovered

Comment: @LukkhaCoder Out of curiosity I signed up a test app to dig the issue. Turns out the login form loads just fine when I send an OAuth request in windows phone IE http://i.imgur.com/4sK0Jpo.jpg

Comment: @LukkhaCoder Are we gonna see a fix soon for that issue with login form isn't showing? I'd love to use MetroStack but this issue is preventing users with SE account from logging in

Comment: @Flint Thanks for helping me debug. Unfortunately I haven't been able to reproduce the issue and therefore don't have a fix so far.

Comment: @LukkhaCoder it informs me that OpenID2.0 for Google accounts has gone away...so can't login and would love to use this...perhaps make it a Windows 10 app while you're at it? :-D

Comment: mathjax helper it will be very ambitious include that in a paid version

Comment: @Flo, See (and upvote) [the related bug report](http://stackapps.com/questions/6302/login-using-google-fails-saying-openid-2-0-accounts-for-google-has-gone-away).

Comment: terrible thing is, that ... OpenID2.0 for Google accounts has gone away. I want to use SE with my current Google account!!!

Comment: @michal: You should be able to login now. They have fixed the issue with OpenID 2.0 and Google. See here: http://stackapps.com/questions/6302/login-using-google-fails-saying-openid-2-0-accounts-for-google-has-gone-away