# WStack - Stack Exchange app for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: app, windows-phone

### Important

Version 2.0.0.0 requires write access for new features so if you are upgrading from an older version please logout and login again to WStack.

### Update

Verion 2.0.0.0 is now live.

- Upvote, downvote and favourite questions
- Upvote and downvote answers
- Upvote comments
- Access to user's own questions from me hub
- Better error handling to minimize number of crashes

### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot, Main Page]

### About

WStack provides a quick access to Stack Exchange sites.

With WStack you can,

- Login to your Stack Exchange account.
- View your Stack Exchange messages, notifications and network
  activity.
- Upvote, downvote and favourite questions / answers / comments
- View your stats on each of your sites.
- Search questions and view answers.
- Search for users and view their profiles.
- Search for tags and badges.
- Periodically check for inbox items and notifications.

#### Download

You can download WStack from [Windows Phone Store](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=99d28169-1337-46fa-b438-4a2352254982).

#### Versions

```
v1.1.0.0
- Initial Release
v1.2.0.0
- Periodic notification and inbox check
- Minor bug fixes
v1.3.0.0
- Direct access to associated question from inbox items
- Light theme support
- Sharing support in question hub
v1.4.0.0
- Pin your favourite sites to start screen for easy access
- Live Tile support for easily tracking reputation and badge count
- You can now view your sites as a list instead of a grid
v2.0.0.0
- Upvote, downvote and favourite questions
- Upvote and downvote answers
- Upvote comments
- Access to user's own questions from me hub
- Better error handling to minimize number of crashes
```

### Contact

For feature requests, suggestions and bugs reports, you can mail me at wstackapp@outlook.com

Comment: Hi! Is this app not available in United Kingdom? When looking at the Windows Phone store I see the message "You can't get apps in this region.".

Comment: Hi @Spencerooni, the app is published last night and it might still be propagating to stores. Are you using WP8.1 btw, it only supports 8.1 version? It is published in United Kingdom, you should have it in a day.

Comment: I was able to download it just now. Really good job! It's really nice! One thing I would say is that I prefer if apps use my theme selection (I prefer black text on white background) but very minor. As you probably know, it's really easy to do using the static resources which Windows Phone has. I am the author of "Stack Mate" for Windows Phone so I was keen to see what you came up with!

Comment: Also searching for a user doesn't seem to work. Everything else seems spot on.

Comment: Hi @Spencerooni thanks for your input, I will look into the problem. I tested the light theme recently and there were many visual problems as I was using wrong StaticResources so I just published my app and left fixing of theme problem to future. By the way your application is very nice too, I recently found out about it and started using it for notifications.

Comment: I can't see the login form if I choose to sign in with StackExchange login. Same issue as I describe here: http://stackapps.com/questions/6094/metro-stack-a-windows-phone-stack-exchange-app?noredirect=1#comment13341_6094

Comment: Hi @Flint I deauthenticated my account and logged in again by selecting StackExchange login method but the authentication page that I saw was different than what you posted. Are you connecting to internet via a proxy, may be it is tampering the SSL connection? I will continue to investigate the problem further.

Comment: Hi @Flint, what is the version of your operating system? Which updates did you get? May you try to login by changing the website preference of IE to mobile version? Thanks.

Comment: @BirkanCilingir It's all good now. The problem seems to have fixed itself (i.imgur.com/CYJRaLc.jpg) after I applied Denim update (was on Cyan before) which was finally available for my Lumia only since last week. Maybe because the app now uses IE11 engine

Comment: @Flint With Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1 Microsoft made a change to user-agent of IE11 in order to emulate Android and iOS and fool web sites (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/07/31/the-mobile-web-should-just-work-for-everyone.aspx). I believe before the update you were directed to normal website instead of the mobile one and were experiencing problems as a result. Other users also reported the same problem. Anyway I will open a question about that to inform SE devs. Hope you enjoy the app.

Comment: Terrible thing is the fact, that is not possible to log via google account due to openID probem.

Comment: @michal I have been informed about this problem before and opened a question with a bug tag on StackApps. You can access it at [Login using Google fails saying OpenID 2.0 accounts for Google has gone away](http://stackapps.com/q/6302)

Comment: @michal login via Google should be fixed now. If you haven't given up on WStack, can you retry to login via Google and inform me about the result :) Thanks.