# Login using Google fails saying OpenID 2.0 accounts for Google has gone away

Tags: bug, status-completed, authentication, oauth2

Recently I have received complaints about my app suggesting that logging in with a Google account shows a warning message that OpenID authentication has gone away. When I tried to log in with my own Google account the same warning was shown to me blocking the login flow.

It seems that the mobile authentication page has not been updated to use the Google OAuth option, and is instead still trying to use the Google OpenID endpoint. Can the mobile authentication page be updated?

Comment: Which authentication page are you talking about? Got a link handy?

Comment: @AnnaLear I am using https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog link for authentication in my app.

Comment: This is not WARNING but ERROR like problem, which is stopping any possibilities to use this app via google account identification.

Comment: @AnnaLear has there been any progress about this problem? Were you able to reproduce it? Do you need more information?

Comment: @BirkanCilingir I looked at this earlier today. I think I see where the problem is, but I don't have the environment on my machine just yet to reproduce/fix. I'll hunt down a way to do that ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this was a fun one. :)

We apparently broke several different things over the course of a year that went unnoticed until Google turned off OpenID support. In no particular order but for fun and posterity:

1. Facebook OAuth authentication just straight up didn't work. It broke back in January of 2014 when the code was accidentally changed from `function loginWithFacebook()` to `function oauth_version()`.
2. Once that was fixed, it turned out that at some point we broke the part of the OAuth flow that would fake a redirect instead of issuing a 302 and running face-first into a denied cross-domain AJAX request. (Google OAuth flow had the same problem.)
3. Tangentially related, we also broke error message display about a month ago when we noticed a weird header being set in the `HandleError` method and figured it was save to remove instead of, I don't know, search for where else it may be used. :P

All in all, a bit of a comedy of errors, starting with "uh, how do I even test this locally?". It's all fixed now, so the Google auth flow in your app should work fine once more.

Comment: Hooray! Happy days! \o/

Comment: I didn't finish the login via Google flow but I was able to pass the page that caused the problem. Thanks for your support :)