# Stack Overflow app for Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 and Android

Tags: app, script, windows-phone, windows

**About**
Windows Phone and Windows 8.1 don't have a Stack Overflow app and I would like to create one for both the platforms.

**Aim:**
To create an app that can be used to browse through the questions on Stack Overflow, answer the questions, ask the questions, perform up-vote, down-vote, comment on the questions/answers, etc.

This is the stackapps.com post required to gain write access, and to document and announce the app.

License
Application is free.

**Platform**
Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1

**Technologies used:**
C#, XAML and third-party libraries like JSON.NET, HTML Agility Pack.

**Update 1**
The app is close to submission. Here are the screenshots.

[image: Start Screen]

[image: User Profile page]

**Update 2**
The app is live. The download link is [here](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/app/stackcook/6fde7977-b260-4ca6-9369-cbca7f9e540a)

**Update 3**
The phone version is live as well. The download link is [here](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/stackcook/9c34fd1b-a44f-4b5b-8932-c7c63db66bcb)

**Update 4**
The [android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackcook) version is released today and this one is for the entire Stack Exchange network.

The demo of the app can be found [here](https://youtu.be/bCKPKKblmVc)
The demo of Share feature can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1RQmmOJXIE)
The demo of Enabling live tiles can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxmHRUCp8Z4)

Comment: There is an unofficial app for Windows Phone now.

#http://stackapps.com/questions/6094/metro-stack-a-windows-phone-stack-exchange-app

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just installed the app on my phone Lumia 730. The app crashed right after logging in. This is almost the same case with all the StackOverflow apps on Windows Phone and none are available on Windows 8 / 8.1

Comment: Shortly I'll update with the screenshots of the work done so far.

Comment: Hey Windows and Windows Phone users, anyone got a chance to use it? How do you like it ? Feedback welcome.

Comment: I'm happy to see an initiative to introduce SO to Windows Phone. Any plans on creating "review" functionality? While I'm on the go I'd be happy to do some fast things like reviewing/editing posts. I'm not yet so experienced to be able to answer questions easily without some additional web search or testing. And it's easier to do these tasks on my regular computer. I think the app would be more successful for reviewing purposes.

Comment: I am working on few enhancements. Sure I'll consider this as one of them. Thanks for your suggestion. You can send me the feedback on appkitchen@outlook.com or better yet in the windows / windows phone store  itself.