# Posting an answer via StackOverflow API

Tags: app, windows-phone, windows

This is in reference to the [StackOverflow for Windows and Windows Phone](https://stackapps.com/q/6098/30879) . I'm in the middle of the development of the app. Right now, I am trying to implement the posting of answers using the API.
My question is, do we have to put the body of the answer in the url itself ?

For eg. Is this how the API should be called ?

`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2//questions/{id}/answers/add?body="is the entire body should be added here ?"?key=key?access_token=access_token`

Comment: I think you can (haven't tested), but normally you would `POST` this.  Be sure to properly URL or Form encode, either way.

Comment: @Jagannath could you give me your contact details...I am finding it difficult to generate access token for my app registered with stackapps...I have client id,client secret...please please reply

Comment: @Jagannath Please check mail